# Zeno's influence on the conception of the Hydra?

Tags: greek, history

I am referring to [Zeno of Elia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_of_Elea) (c.490 –c.430 BCE) and his famous [Dichotomy Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox). This paradox has to do with infinite divisions based on 1/2.

It seems to be that the conception of the Hydra as growing two heads for every one that is severed occurs only after Zeno.  (This is a reverse of his paradox, in the form of infinite expansion through doubling.)

This new conception of the Hydra is attributed to Euripides (c.480 – c.406 BCE).  Although I am having trouble locating the exact passage at the moment, it does re-occur some centuries later with [Pseudo-Apollodorus, Bibliotheca 2. 77 - 80](http://www.theoi.com/Text/Apollodorus2.html).

**Is there any evidence that Zeno influenced this new conception of the Hydra, by suggesting the underlying mathematics of the narrative gimmick?**

I suspect not, but if there is an example of this conception of the Hydra before the fifth century, it would disprove the connection.

Comment: Euripides mentions Hydra regenerating its heads in _Herakles_, but I don't think he explicitly tells us that she grew _two_ new heads for each lost one. I think the oldest known source for that is Diodorus (4.11.5).

Comment: @yannis I was reading through the Euripides to confirm when I got really busy.  (Wasn't able to find the passage on simple search, but I am interested in the original wording.)